# Docker-compose up missing files

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

My question is simple , when docker-compose build : some new folders will be generated using npm run prod command , I've added in my Dockerfile "ls -lhtr the_missingFolder" and I can see it's there.

After complete building I ran docker-compose up >> Boomm the folder not in the container , why ?

How can I fix that please.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt install -y  build-essential

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git libpng-dev zlib1g-dev libicu-dev libtool g++

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends apt-utils

RUN apt install -y composer

RUN apt-get install -y curl wget

RUN apt-get install -y  autoconf automake pkg-config libgtk-3-dev nasm

RUN apt-get clean && apt-get update && apt-get install -y locales
RUN locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8

RUN apt-get install -y python-software-properties

RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common

RUN LC_ALL=C.UTF-8 add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt install -y php7.1-fpm php7.1-mbstring php7.1-xmlrpc php7.1-soap 
php7.1-gd php7.1-xml php7.1-cli php7.1-zip php7.1-pgsql php7.1-curl

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | bash -

RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . ./

COPY package*.json ./

RUN cp .env.docker .env

RUN npm install

RUN npm run prod

COPY . /usr/src/app/

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN composer update

RUN composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader

RUN php artisan config:clear

RUN php artisan optimize

CMD bash -c "php artisan db:seed --class=App\\module\\role\\database\\seed\\role"

CMD bash -c "php artisan db:seed --class=App\\module\\notification\\database\\seed\\notification"

CMD bash -c "php artisan notifications:generate-files"

CMD bash -c "php artisan migrate"

CMD bash -c "composer install && php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000"

EXPOSE 8000
```

Best regards

Comment: Make sure that your image is not built by multi stages

Comment: Commonly caused by multi stage builds as already said or you implicitly delete them by other calls (e.g. something like a npm clean script). Depending on the kind of folder, its common to delete things like build tools that were not required at runtime to keep the image size small.
Please clarify your question by adding your complete Dockerfile, so that we can see what's happening during the build.

Comment: thanks for quick response , I've added the Docekrfile above in the question.

Comment: just a note may could help , when I use "docker run " to run my app container : I can see the missing files there .. but with docker-compose up I can't see them.

Comment: Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be // docker-compose version 1.16.1, build 6d1ac21

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before. In my case, I had a named volume that gets reused every time `docker-compose up` is ran.

I just destroyed the volume along with the containers using `-v` option in `docker-compose down` and everything is there the next time I ran `docker-compose up`.